# How to make an element with variable width always stick out a specific width?

Tags: html, css

I have a div that has a variable width, depending on its content. I want to use it for a menu bar that slides in from the side of the page when the user clicks it, so it has to stick out. I want it to stick out exactly 16px (because the arrow image has that size), no matter how wide it actually is.
How can I realize that without using JavaScript?

**EDIT**:
Thanks for your answers! But it came to my mind that I could do it just like I did with the navbar on that site – modify the width instead of sliding it in.
See here: http://dev.mezgrman.de/tagwall/

Comment: Maybe you can give us a link with what you have so far or you can use this instead: http://jsfiddle.net/ It's hard to imagine what you want to actually do.

Comment: Sure. Here's the project: http://dev.mezgrman.de/tagwall/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by modifying the width of my element now. Silly me.

Comment: Great! Also the concept is very interesting!

Comment: You mean the tag wall concept or what?

Comment: The wall concept! Keep it going...:)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that is to add another class to your menu item when it is collapsed and set another width there and a text indent like so (instead of write again all your css in a new class)

```
.collapsed {
    width: 16px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background: url("/images/arrow_left.png") no-repeat scroll right center rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
}
```

Now the only thing you have to do in javascript is to add and remove that class depending on the user's click. (You won't get rid of javascript. because css doesn't know when you click an element)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/LruWn/

No matter how long the .box is, it will always overlap the .container only by exactly 16px:

#### html:

```
<div class="container"><div class="box">text</div></div>​
```

#### css:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    outline: 1px solid red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.box {
    width: 70px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    margin-left: -16px;
    outline: 1px solid black;
}​
```

Add `overflow: hidden;` to `.container` to see how it might look like in action.